# Aplicar Color fondo PHPWORD

Tags: php, phpword

Estoy trabajando con PHPWORD, tengo una tabla que tiene solo 2 columnas y 5 filas, hasta ahora logro aplicar un color de fondo a toda la tabla pero lo que necesito es que cada columna tenga un color diferente pero la verdad no se como hacerlo, agradecería su ayuda.
Mi código es el siguiente:

```
 $styleTable = array('borderColor' => '000000', 'borderSize' => 6, 'cellMargin' => 50, 
 'bgColor' => 'f2dbdb', 'size' => '12', 'bold' => true,);

 $styleTable2 = array('borderColor' => '000000', 'borderSize' => 6, 'cellMargin' => 50, 
 'bgColor' => 'FFFFFF', 'size' => '12', 'bold' => true,);

 $documento->addTableStyle('myTable', $styleTable);
 $table = $seccion->addTable('myTable');

 $table->addRow();
 $cell = $table->addCell(3600);
 $cell->addText('COORDINADOR CAMPOS CLINICOS SOLICITANTE');
 $cell = $table->addCell(5500);
 $cell->addText('');

 $table->addRow();
 $cell = $table->addCell(3600);
 $cell->addText('CARRERA');
 $cell = $table->addCell(5500);
 $cell->addText('');

 $table->addRow();
 $cell = $table->addCell(3600);
 $cell->addText('CENTRO FORMADOR');
 $cell = $table->addCell(5500);
 $cell->addText('');

 $table->addRow();
 $cell = $table->addCell(3600);
 $cell->addText('PRÁCTICA CURRICULAR O INTERNADO (INDICAR LO QUE CORRESPONDE)');
 $cell = $table->addCell(5500);
 $cell->addText('');

 $table->addRow();
 $cell = $table->addCell(3600);
 $cell->addText('DOCENTE ENCARGADA DE PRÁCTICA (CONTACTO Y CORREO ELECTRONICO)');
 $cell = $table->addCell(5500);
 $cell->addText('');
```

Comment: Segun la documentacion el elemento `$cell`, admite la propiedad `bgColor` , entonces deberia ser posible declarar una variable de tipo array y enviar esa variable junto al valor: ejemplo con `$myCellStyle = array('bgColor'=>'038cd4');` y en enviar `$cell = $table->addCell(3600, [$myCellStyle]);` [documentacion](https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/elements.html) ; No lo pongo como repuesta porque es la primera vez que escucho PHPWORD, pero deberias intentarlo.

Comment: Me funciono, muchas gracias, el ultimo codigo quedaria asi $cell = $table->addCell(3600, $myCellStyle);